# Unconnected Territory Civ5

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

My civilization has acquired an unconnected tile(see picture below).

[image]

How is this possible? Or simply a glitch?

EDIT: zoomed out version

[image]

I'm thinking it's because El Mirador is being squeezed on all sides it some how determined the floating hex was closest available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some factors at work

1. Generally, cultural tile acquisition prioritizes tiles that can be worked by a city. From your screenshots, it looks like there are no available tiles that can be worked by your cities.
2. Cultural expansion tends to favor tiles with resources. I see coal in the acquired tile.
3. There is no requirement that all of your territory be contiguous, even new territory acquired through cultural expansion. I have regularly seen civs gain non-contiguous territory through cultural expansion.